# Dynamic div that grows with content but starts filling whole page

Tags: css

Thanks in advance. Right now I have a problem with "content" and "footer" which are in "wrapper". Here are the stylings for these.

```
#content
{

   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   background-color: #b2b2b2;

}

#footer
{

   width: 100%;
   min-height: 40px;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #e23e23;

}

#wrapper
{

   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: green;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;

}
```

This is all good except I want content to take up the rest of the height of the page (except footer). Any method I use to do this makes it so that if I overfill content, the content goes past and under footer.

In other words I want content and footer to take up the height of the window but if content is overfilled it should push the footer down and create a scroll bar.

Can this be done with css and if not how do i do it with JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a "sticky footer". Here are a few references:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/
- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/